# Apostrophe breaking search on oledb?

Tags: vb.net, vba, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, oledb

I have a search string in my code, and whenever the user types in the search box `txt_search` I have a datagridview that updates itself.

However, it seems that simply putting an apostrophe in the searchbox causes the program to break.

```
Dim search As String
search = txt_serial3.Text
dv = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
bs.DataSource = dv
bs.Filter = "[SerialNumber] = '" & search & "'"
data_excel.DataSource = bs
```

This is the line of code I'm using to search and update the datagridview, is there either

A) a way of modifying this to make it pick up the apostrophe or

B) a way of disabling apostrophe inputs at all in the searchbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic example of a sql injection bug. The program thinks the single quite is the end of the data. A trick I've used is to replace a single quote with [two single quotes](http://net-informations.com/vbprj/ado.net/single-quotes.htm). Try

```
bs.Filter = "[SerialNumber] = '" & Replace(search,"'","''") & "'"
```

Comment: You can improve this answer by pointing out *specifically* what it's doing, and explaining *why*.

Comment: Using the replace function like that I've commonly used `     It's the character right under the ~ on your keyboard. I think it's easier on the eyes and SQL won't complain about it.

Answer (score 0):

To extend on Russell's Answer. You need to sanitise inputs before using them. If you do not, special characters can interfere with other functions. Think of the possibilities and try to adjust and cater for inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just stop them all together from entering a ' in instead of replacing it, you can use this little bit of code.

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    If keyData = (Keys.Oem7) Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
    End If
End Function
```

So what this does, it catches every keystroke pressed. If it is a ' it will just ignore it all together. It's just another alternative depending your situation.